# Downloading from audio html5 tags

Tags: javascript, html, audio, tags

In HTML5, is there a way to download the current song in an audio tag? I am feeding it an octet stream that it is playing, but the user cannot directly download the song from the link. Is there a way to allow the user to download the song that is playing? Audio shows up as transparent so there is no way for the user to do a simple right click + save as. Can you encapsulate audio in something that has a save as ability? Or maybe some JavaScript might do the trick?

Comment: Any reason you can't just link to it in an `<a href="">` tag? As for it being "transparent," the `audio` tag does have controls that can be styled, although that won't affect your situation regarding downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a link if it's not a live streaming audio. If it's live streaming, I don't think you can download it with a browser because it doesn't have a finite file size.

If it's a problem about download file naming, you can use `content-disposition` header. It should be like this:

`content-disposition: attachment; filename=playing.mp3`

Adding this to the header shouldn't affect the streaming to the audio tag.

Answer (score 1):

If the audio is served it means that the audio file is present.

You can even make a link to the audio file and it should work.

Comment: The reason I cannot link it is because it is an octet stream, so that's what the user will be downloading. The audio tag is interpreting the stream. At least I think that's how it works. When I tried downloading from the link using firefox, it didnt have a proper file extension.

Comment: I dont feel comfortable posting a link to our project in development

Comment: I did some searching around, and the pandora google-chrome-extension uses them. Here is an example of one of their links:

http://audio-sv5-t2-2.pandora.com/access/7689012287793288843?version=4&lid=307468573&token=xkShK1Afzv4uKVXXDfEmhuZuCXF8QAnPRl8YF6Hc%2FiPVjlLzFLyOSiqJL4t886vzenS7C94vSThZZvmveyZTs3TZ1vJP%2BRJh%2FJK6qd%2BnzEn7qrFnhP6N2j%2FhmQiZ4YLlh72qoAB%2F4trzD1naKBL7chohfVjDlea%2BrMGQKSgmTriXjQh8l8STxfa1RbqzjwmBOPLeIv9ZVeEGnLMirTM4gev1S%2BfMkTdEAiPRlNogk7SpllqbgPTdc8XyqgahEr7HFAZRCtWRVjK65hwV8hhJqY%2B93lbWjmNz6PAJ2KzXwl%2F0swxK7E4gCFxVr%2Bl9osN8yrEzyT%2BJFh7y7CTrTZ75jA%3D%3D

Comment: How do you do that using JavaScript? I don't want to have the user having to follow a bunch of directions.

Comment: @DazSlayer You can't, if you want the file to have a .mp3 extension for the user then it has to have a .mp3 extension when sent by the server.